# Symfony2 : extends web profiler to include more security related datas

Tags: php, symfony

I was wondering how to include more informations in the security tab from symfony2's web profiler. The informations I would like to add are available in the user entity.

I've found that very detailed article : [data_collector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html) but it did not explain how to extend an existing tab.

Thanks

Comment: juste to revive the question...